# Unsure of what code Error is

Tags: php

I have been working on a code to change someone's password in a database (such as if they forgot their code) using variables from a database such as their secret code.

Whenever I attempt to run the function I always get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhysicsProject\resetPasswordConnection.php on line 70.

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
   <?php
include ('inc/header.php');


$userUsername1 = $_POST['userUsername'];
$userChangePassword = md5($_POST['userChangePassword']);
$userChangePasswordConfirm = md5($_POST['userChangePasswordConfirm']);
$userSecretCode = md5($_POST['userSecretCode']);
$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM userinformation WHERE user_username = '" . $userUsername1 . "'";

$data2 = mysql_query($sql4, $cn) or
  die (mysql_error($cn));
$rowPW = mysql_num_rows($data2);
$row1214 = mysql_fetch_assoc($data2);
$DBuName = $row1214['user_username'];
$DBCode = $row1214['user_code'];

  if ($userUsername1 == $DBuName){
    if ($userSecretCode == $DBCode){  
      if ($rowPW == 1){
        if ($userChangePassword != $userChangePasswordConfirm){?>
          <div class = "container" id = "bodyContainerVideo">
            <div class = "row">
              <div class = "col-md-12">
                <h1 class = "Main-Title">Your new passwords do not match.</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html><?php 
  } else {
      $sql5 = "UPDATE userinformation SET user_password = '" . $userChangePassword . "' WHERE user_username = '" . $userUsername1 . "'";
          $result5 = mysql_query($sql7, $cn) or
          die(mysql_error($cn));?>
    <div class = "container" id = "bodyContainerVideo">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
          <h1 class = "Main-Title">Your password has been sucessfully been changed</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
      }
    } else {?>
    <div class = "container" id = "bodyContainerVideo">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
          <h1 class = "Main-Title">The code that you put in is incorrect</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
    <?php}
  } else {?>
    <div class = "container" id = "bodyContainerVideo">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-12">
          <h1 class = "Main-Title">Username does not exist.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>  
  <?php }
  } 
include ('inc/footer.php');
?>
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this (Should be line 58):

```
<?php}
```

to this (You need just 1 space min.):

```
<?php  //this also works <?php } but this not <?php}
}
```

Comment: That definitely helped! Now I just need to get it to work. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Witt Nice! your welcome, have a nice day :D (BTW: you can upvote and accept answer's how helped you!)

Comment: I tried to, but it wouldn't let me. It said I need 15 reputation.

Comment: yeah, lol. Thanks again! hopefully I will figure out how to get this code to be working properly. Its getting there.